# Creating a dynamic grid of controls in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, grid

I'm working on a personal project, and I want to create a simple GUI to accomplish this project.(Using C#) My main goal for this project is the creation of a custom grid of squares. What I would like is for the user to be able to click any of the generated squares on the GUI, and be able to change the color of that square. Now, I've looked for the past few nights but I haven't had any luck with finding anything to fit that sort of request.

Would it be easier for me to create square button controls ahead of time and just hide the ones I don't use? Or is it at all possible to dynamically create buttons in a grid shape? Or is there something more efficient than using buttons that can change color?

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: I'm planning on using Winforms, and I was going to build this GUI using a desktop application.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - What would the squares do/contain? Just a Color??

Comment: Both WPF and ASP.NET have very nice mechanisms for creating dynamic repeating controls like that.  Which do you prefer - web or desktop?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm targeting Winforms, and I'm planning on creating a desktop GUI.

Comment: If all you want to change is the color of squares there are many many options. You can use a DataGridView, a TableLayoutPanel, Buttons, Panels or Labels, maybe added to a FlowLayoutPanel; all these can be created dynamically. Or even just colored pixels you draw in a Paint event or into a Bitmap. You need to think and tell much more about what it shall really lead to. A Couple of colored squares hardly qualify as a 'GUI'..